# How to get unique values by line - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the minute difference between ids (sut to sut1), but I don't know how do this in SQL Server.

Now my query is resulting this table:

[image]

But I want this result:

[image]

My query:

```
select distinct
    sct.SystemUnitTRID as id_sut,
    sct1.SystemUnitTRID as id_sut1,
    sct.ModifiedDateTime as sut,
    sct1.ModifiedDateTime as sut1,
    DATEDIFF(minute, sct.ModifiedDateTime, sct1.ModifiedDateTime) as diff
from 
    systemunittransactions sct
    left join SystemUnitTransactions sct1 on sct1.ServiceTag = 
    sct.ServiceTag
where 
    sct.servicetag = 'IDXXX12' 
    and sct1.ServiceTag = 'IDXX12' 
    and sct.StatusType = 'STATUS_1'
    and sct1.StatusType = 'STATUS_1'
    and sct.SystemUnitTRID != sct1.SystemUnitTRID
order by 
    sct.SystemUnitTRID
```

Comment: And how are your new diffs calculated?  It is not obvious.

Comment: @Gordon I see your point here. My answer is probably making some wrong assumptions. :(

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to calculate the diff from the next date time. I cant calculate using min and max

Comment: Note - whenever you use an outer join and then refer to a column in the unpreserved table in the where clause (in this example sct1) you logically transform the outer join into an inner join. In addition, the use of distinct in any query is often a hack used to overcome logical errors in your query - that is a problem you should resolve first. lag/lead is probably a better approach but much depends on your schema and usage.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want to use this code. First you create a CTE, with a group by. After that, you calculate the diff:

```
USE YourDB;
WITH Cte AS 
(
     SELECT Sct.Systemunittrid AS Id_Sut,
            Sct1.Systemunittrid AS Id_Sut1,
            MIN(Sct.Modifieddatetime) AS Sut,
            MAX(Sct1.Modifieddatetime) AS Sut1
     FROM Systemunittransactions AS Sct
       LEFT JOIN Systemunittransactions AS Sct1 ON Sct1.Servicetag = Sct.Servicetag
     WHERE Sct.Servicetag = 'IDXXX12'
           AND Sct1.Servicetag = 'IDXX12'
           AND Sct.Statustype = 'STATUS_1'
           AND Sct1.Statustype = 'STATUS_1'
           AND Sct.Systemunittrid != Sct1.Systemunittrid
     GROUP BY Sct.Systemunittrid,
              Sct1.Systemunittrid 
)

SELECT *, DATEDIFF(minute, Sct.Modifieddatetime, Sct1.Modifieddatetime) AS Diff
FROM Cte;
```

Comment: @iamdave the upvotes originated from a time when the logic was not well explained. I made an educated guess at that point, which turned out to have some wrong assumptions. Plus one for your solution, upvoted.

Comment: Daniel's solution using `lag` or `lead` should  be the preferred answer if they are available to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or newer you can simply use LAG or LEAD functions depending what do yo need

```
select distinct
    SystemUnitTRID as id_sut,
    lead(SystemUnitTRID) over (order by systemunittrid) as id_sut1,
    ModifiedDateTime as sut,
    lead(ModifiedDateTime) over (order by systemunittrid) as sut1,
    DATEDIFF(minute, lead(ModifiedDateTime) over (order by systemunittrid), ModifiedDateTime) as diff
from 
    systemunittransactions sct
where 
    servicetag = 'IDXXX12'
and statustype = 'STATUS_1'
order by 
    SystemUnitTRID
```

Comment: I do not think you need to include the `distinct` here.  If you add a `partition` to your `over` clause, this can work on multiple `ServiceTag` groupings as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your example, you are joining by the serviceTag

```
Systemunittransactions AS Sct
       LEFT JOIN Systemunittransactions AS Sct1 ON Sct1.Servicetag = Sct.Servicetag
```

but after that you filter by two different tags on each table,

```
Sct.Servicetag = 'IDXXX12' AND Sct1.Servicetag = 'IDXX12',
```

one has one more X than the other. That join with that filter would never work.
Assuming that it is a missing letter error in the question, and the table example that you are given which doesn't have more than one row with the same pair of id's, the query you're looking for is:

```
select 
    sct.SystemUnitTRID as id_sut,
    sct1.SystemUnitTRID as id_sut1,
    sct.ModifiedDateTime as sut,
    sct1.ModifiedDateTime as sut1,
    DATEDIFF(minute, sct.ModifiedDateTime, sct1.ModifiedDateTime) as diff
from 
    systemunittransactions sct
    left join SystemUnitTransactions sct1 on sct1.ServiceTag = 
    sct.ServiceTag and sct.StatusType = sct1.StatusType
where 
    sct.servicetag = 'IDXXX12'  
    and sct.StatusType = 'STATUS_1'
    and sct.SystemUnitTRID != sct1.SystemUnitTRID
order by 
    sct.SystemUnitTRID
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use `lag` and `lead` per the other answers here, you can achieve the same effect by creating a `row_number` with the `ServiceTag` as the `partition` and sort it by the `ModifiedDateTime` you can `join` the data to itself via the `ServiceTag` and the `row_number` to get your periods between each row.  You will note that this works for multiple `ServiceTag` values:

```
declare @t table(ServiceTag varchar(20), StatusType varchar(20), SystemUnitTRID int, ModifiedDateTime datetime);
insert into @t values
 ('IDXXX12','STATUS_1',145818840,'2019/01/18 08:35:27')
,('IDXXX12','STATUS_1',145820934,'2019/01/18 08:50:41')
,('IDXXX12','STATUS_1',145822116,'2019/01/18 08:59:18')
,('IDXXX12','STATUS_1',145825658,'2019/01/18 09:23:23')
,('IDXXX12','STATUS_1',145826849,'2019/01/18 09:30:55')
,('IDXXX13','STATUS_1',245818840,'2019/01/17 18:35:00')
,('IDXXX13','STATUS_1',245820934,'2019/01/17 18:50:00')
,('IDXXX13','STATUS_1',245822116,'2019/01/17 18:59:00')
,('IDXXX13','STATUS_1',245825658,'2019/01/17 19:23:00')
,('IDXXX13','STATUS_1',245826849,'2019/01/17 21:30:00')
,('IDXXX14','STATUS_2',345818840,'2019/01/16 18:35:00')
,('IDXXX14','STATUS_2',345820934,'2019/01/16 18:50:00')
,('IDXXX14','STATUS_2',345822116,'2019/01/16 18:59:00')
,('IDXXX14','STATUS_2',345825658,'2019/01/16 19:23:00')
,('IDXXX14','STATUS_2',345826849,'2019/01/16 19:30:00')
;

with d as
(
    select ServiceTag
            ,StatusType
            ,SystemUnitTRID
            ,ModifiedDateTime
            ,row_number() over (partition by ServiceTag order by ModifiedDateTime) as rn
    from @t
    where StatusType = 'STATUS_1'
)
select d.ServiceTag
    ,d.SystemUnitTRID as id_sut
    ,d2.SystemUnitTRID as id_sut1
    ,d.ModifiedDateTime as sut
    ,d2.ModifiedDateTime as sut1
    ,datediff(minute,d.ModifiedDateTime,d2.ModifiedDateTime) as MinuteBoundaries    -- Returns the number of minute boundaries crossed
    ,datediff(second,d.ModifiedDateTime,d2.ModifiedDateTime)/60 as WholeMinutes -- Returns the number of whole minutes
    ,right('00' + cast(datediff(second,d.ModifiedDateTime,d2.ModifiedDateTime)/60/60 as varchar(10)),2)
        + ':'
        + right('00' + cast(datediff(second,d.ModifiedDateTime,d2.ModifiedDateTime)/60%60 as varchar(10)),2) as FormattedTime
from d
    join d as d2
        on d.ServiceTag = d2.ServiceTag
            and d.rn = d2.rn-1
order by d.ServiceTag
        ,d.ModifiedDateTime;
```

## Output

```
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+
| ServiceTag |  id_sut   |  id_sut1  |           sut           |          sut1           | MinuteBoundaries | WholeMinutes | FormattedTime |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+
| IDXXX12    | 145818840 | 145820934 | 2019-01-18 08:35:27.000 | 2019-01-18 08:50:41.000 |               15 |           15 | 00:15         |
| IDXXX12    | 145820934 | 145822116 | 2019-01-18 08:50:41.000 | 2019-01-18 08:59:18.000 |                9 |            8 | 00:08         |
| IDXXX12    | 145822116 | 145825658 | 2019-01-18 08:59:18.000 | 2019-01-18 09:23:23.000 |               24 |           24 | 00:24         |
| IDXXX12    | 145825658 | 145826849 | 2019-01-18 09:23:23.000 | 2019-01-18 09:30:55.000 |                7 |            7 | 00:07         |
| IDXXX13    | 245818840 | 245820934 | 2019-01-17 18:35:00.000 | 2019-01-17 18:50:00.000 |               15 |           15 | 00:15         |
| IDXXX13    | 245820934 | 245822116 | 2019-01-17 18:50:00.000 | 2019-01-17 18:59:00.000 |                9 |            9 | 00:09         |
| IDXXX13    | 245822116 | 245825658 | 2019-01-17 18:59:00.000 | 2019-01-17 19:23:00.000 |               24 |           24 | 00:24         |
| IDXXX13    | 245825658 | 245826849 | 2019-01-17 19:23:00.000 | 2019-01-17 21:30:00.000 |              127 |          127 | 02:07         |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-`select * from(select  sct.SystemUnitTRID as id_sut, sct1.SystemUnitTRID as id_sut1, sct.ModifiedDateTime as sut, sct1.ModifiedDateTime as sut1, DATEDIFF(minute, sct.ModifiedDateTime, sct1.ModifiedDateTime) as diff, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by sct.SystemUnitTRID order by sct.SystemUnitTRID) as rownum from systemunittransactions sct
 left join SystemUnitTransactions sct1 on sct1.ServiceTag =  sct.ServiceTag where sct.servicetag = 'IDXXX12'and sct1.ServiceTag = 'IDXX12' and sct.StatusType = 'STATUS_1'and sct1.StatusType = 'STATUS_1'and sct.SystemUnitTRID != sct1.SystemUnitTRID)t where rownum=1`